# PostgreSQL table: How can I find a list of values that were inserted during a given time period?

Tags: postgresql, time

Is there a Postgres function that would allow me to find which values were inserted during/after a giving time period, even if that given table/row does not have a timestamp value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can find the involved transaction ids by looking at the hidden system columns xmin and xmax, but you can't find the timestamp.